# Grails: Problem with nested associations in criteria builder

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria, grails-orm, hibernate-criteria

I have a frustrating problem with the criteria builder. I have an application in which one user has one calendar, and a calendar has many entries. Seems straightforward enough, but when I try to get the calendar entries for a given user, I can't access the user property (MissingMethodException). Here's the code:

```
def getEntries(User user) {
  def entries = [ClassName].createCriteria().list() {
    calendar {
      user {
        eq("id", user.id)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have even tried the following variation:

```
def getEntries(User user) {
  def entries = [ClassName].createCriteria().list() {
    calendar {
      eq("user", user)
    }
  }
}
```

That did not raise an exception, but didn't work either.

Here's the relevant parts of the domain classes:

```
class Calendar {
    static belongsTo = [user: User]
    static hasMany = [entries: Entries]

    ...
}

class User {
    Calendar calendar

    ...
}

class Entry {
    static belongsTo = [calendar: Calendar]

    ...
}
```

When Googling I came across a similar problem noted in early 2008:
http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-1412

But according to that link this issue should have been solved long ago.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you turn on org.hibernate.SQL debug loging and see what query it's running? That might help track down what's going wrong.

Comment: I tried that, what I got was:

Q1: select this_.id as id8_0_, this_.version as version8_0_, ...
from user this_ where this_.username=?

Q2: select top ? count(*) as y0_ from entry this_ left
outer join calendar calendar_a1_ on this_.calendar_id=calendar_a1_.id 
where ((calendar_a1_.id=?))

Q3: select top ? this_.id as id3_1_, this_.version as version3_1_, ...
from entry this_ left outer join calendar calendar_a1_ on this_.calendar_id=calendar_a1_.id 
where ((calendar_a1_.id=?))

This seems fine to me. Any ideas? (Sorry about the formatting, comments don't seem to treat code very nicely.)

Comment: I don't see anything about 'where calender.user_id = ?' though...

Comment: It looks correct to me. I'd create a simple project using your classes and attach it to a new JIRA bug.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found the error!! The error wasn't at all related to criteria builder. The problem in this case was that I had user variable in the scope, so when I tried to enter the user relation by

```
calendar {
  user {
    eq("id", user.id)
  }
}
```

Grails thought that I wanted to call the user object/variable with a closure. I can once again use criteria builders freely :-)

Thanks for all your help and suggestions guys!

Comment: joy of the internet. 6 years later this question saved me SO much debugging time.

Answer (score 3):

If you have such scope errors like the poster of the question, you always can do the following. Lets say you have a user variable in your scope, then use

```
def user = User.get(...)
...
calendar {
  'user' {
    eq("id", user.id)
  }
}
```

instead of

```
def user = User.get(...)
...
calendar {
  user {
    eq("id", user.id)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your criteria isn't working.  I've always had some problems getting them to work quite right and find them more fiddly than HQL.

You could just use HQL for your query, which I find more natural to write and easier to parse since I'm used to looking as SQL.

Here's your query in HQL:

```
Entry.executeQuery("from Entry e where e.calendar.user.id = :userId", [userId: theUser.id])
```

Comment: Thanks Ted, I'd much prefer to have criteria since I think they are more readable and easier to refactor. But I will use HQL in the meanwhile, but it disturbs me that criteria builder isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a thing

```
def getEntries(User user) {
 def entries = Entries.createCriteria().list() {
          calendar { 
             user { 
              eq("id", user.id)
             }
          } 
      }  
}
```

Comment: sorry I misspelled earlier, It should of course be 
    eq("id", user.id)
but that didn't work either, I still get the same error...

Answer (score 0):

```
def entries = Entries.createCriteria().list() {
```

Why did you wrote **Entries**? Your Classname is **Entry**. 
So i would say your Line should read:

```
def entries = Entry.createCriteria().list() {
```

Comment: You're right, another misspell from my part. Howerver, this still doesn't fix my problem :-(